# React <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr> Warning

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting the following warnings in a React component:

[image]

The related code is the following:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap'; 

const MyComponent = (params) => {

function onSelect(event) {
    params.onSelect(event, params.data.id);
}

return (
    <tr key={params.data.id}>
        {params.isSelectable ? (
            <Checkbox onChange={onSelect}>
                <td>{params.data.firstName}&nbsp;</td>
                <td>{params.data.lastName}&nbsp;</td>
            </Checkbox>
        ) : (
            <div>
                <td>{params.data.firstName}&nbsp;</td>
                <td>{params.data.lastName}&nbsp;</td>
            </div>
        )}
    </tr>
);
```

};

If I remove the div tags, I get the following error:

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

I am new to React, so i am not quite clear on what is going on here. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Update: my React version is 15.3.2.

Comment: Divs as children of table rows is invalid HTML. Only table headers or table cells can be children of rows.

Comment: `<td>` belong inside `<tr>` only. The clue is in the question. Also `<div>` should be within a `<td>` or `<th>` if required to be within table contents

Comment: Show your `Checkbox` component...Try to replicate your problem [**here**](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/jYryOv?editors=1011)

Comment: @DhavalJardosh my Checkbox component is from the 'react-bootstrap' library. I didn't create it.

Comment: [**This**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-groups-checkbox-radio) is what you are talking about, right?

Comment: Nope, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682406/how-to-get-values-properties-from-a-react-bootstrap-checkbox

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems with your code

1. Only td and th are allowed inside tr
2. <strike>In React version < 15, you have to wrap tags in one element, when you try to render them. In React 16,</strike> you can now do the following :

   ```
   [
     <td key={1}>{params.data.firstName}&nbsp;</td>,
     <td key={2}>{params.data.lastName}&nbsp;</td>
   ]
   ```

   instead of wrapping the `td`s inside a `div`

I also suggest you extract your logic outside of the `tr`

Comment: Can i do this in React version 15.3.2?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to return several elements and can't have a wrapper (such as in this case), you have a new option as of React 16.2. [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
<React.Fragment>
  <td>{params.data.firstName}&nbsp;</td>
  <td>{params.data.lastName}&nbsp;</td>
</React.Fragment>
```

Or, you might be able to simplify it as:

```
<>
  <td>{params.data.firstName}&nbsp;</td>
  <td>{params.data.lastName}&nbsp;</td>
</>
```

The fragments won't resolve to any HTML element, so the `<td>`s will be direct children of your `<tr>`.

Comment: I can't do that because my React version is 15.3.2.

Comment: or if you dont have that transpilation config setup to recognize <> and </> you can more explicitly do:
`<React.Fragment>
...
</React.Fragment>`